# Pooling annual staff survey data for analysis

Tags: correlation, survey, pooling, cross-section

Every year since 2016 all of the nurses (n~100/year) are asked to complete a survey on job satisfaction and wellbeing. I'm interested in conducting a correlation analysis (Spearman's) to determine which job aspects the survey asks about are correlated, as well as a logistic regression to predict the response to one of the questions (job satisfaction). The data has been deidentified, and there is minimal turnover, so I've got years of survey data without a way to pair responses or weight them. I don't know for sure, but considering the response rate (~70%) and the minimal amount of turnover, most of the responses are coming from the same people every year. I've received advice to pool all of the data together and just acknowledge the limitation of multiple respondents. This doesn't sit well with me, because it seems like the results will be diluted by individuals who have completed the survey as many as 7 times. What are my options?